# NetSuite: Change the default role when a customer registers on web store

Tags: netsuite

I customized the default Customer Center role in NetSuite to extend the functionality our customers have.

Where in NS do I change the default role when people register online? I want new registrations to have this new role, not the default Customer Center role.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an Administrator go to:
Setup -> Company -> General Preferences
find "Default Role for New Customers"
set that.

Comment: Sent a note to my admin about this. I'll up vote once we've made the change. Thanks so much!!

Comment: hello I have same task. 
is their any section to call cUrl after successfully register user on net-suite web site.
pls let me know.